# There are broken links in the help on-topic page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

The help page https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic contains at least three broken links.

1. "ask and answer your own question"
2. "What types of questions should I avoid asking?"
3. "look around"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are fixed, thanks for finding them. If I had a heap of internet points to bestow on you I would :)